# multer req.files undefined with axios in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I want to post a formData using axios to node js route and then save image files into images folder. I'm using multer to read multipart/form-data from axios. I'm receiving productInfo object from req.body which is correct. here is my code:

```
const addNewProduct = () => {

        const newProduct = {
            name: name,
            cost: cost,
            size: size,
            color: color,
            material: material,
            discount: discount,
            description: description,
            category: category
        };

        const nulls  = Object.values(newProduct).filter(p => p === null);

        if(nulls.length === 0 && images.imageFiles) {
            let productFormData = new FormData();
            productFormData.append('productInfo', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
            productFormData.append('productImages', [...images.imageFiles]);
    
            const addUrl = "http://localhost:8080/cpnl/addproduct";
            axios({
                method: "POST",
                url: addUrl,
                data: productFormData,
                headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data.msg);
                })
                .catch((response) => {
                    console.error(response);
                });
        }else {
            Notiflix.Notify.Warning("Check your inputs!");
            console.log(nulls);
            console.log("product: \n" + JSON.stringify(newProduct));
        }
};
```

then I receive the data in node js using multer like this:

**multer config:**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/images",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
}).array("productImages");

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null,true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }
}
```

**multer route:**

```
router.post('/addproduct', async (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                msg: err
            });
        } else {
            if(req.files == undefined) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    msg: "Error: No file selected! please contact the developer."
                });
            } else {
                //problem occures here
                console.log( "images: " + req.body.productImages + "\n");
                data = req.body.productInfo;
                res.status(200).json({
                    msg: "Files uploaded!"
                });
                console.log("data" + data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm receiving image files inside req.body.productImages as Object file.
all of this code looks good at first but multer isn't uploading image files!
why images are inside **req.body.productImages**?
why they aren't inside **req.files**?
what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

In your ***multer route*** code you need to change like following way

```
router.post('/addproduct', upload, async (req, res, next) => {/**
  YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
*/}
```

Because `upload` is a multer reference and returns express middleware. So it will update `req` object with required values you're expecting `req.files`.

**Note:** req.body.productImages exist because `req` object not processed by `multer`

Comment: excuse me. I should have closed the question. thanks for the answer. I just found the solution and added new code in descriptions.

Comment: Can you please explain the solution mr Parham Moieni I am also facing same issue with multer